# Web view in android not using in document navigation

Tags: android, html, webview

So i'm building simple app in android that contains a webview with a lot of data, that's why i implemented in page navigation with links. I'm using something like that:

```
  <a name="top">Web start</a></br>
  <a href="#title1" class="a1">title1</a></br>
  <a href="#title2" class="a1">titel2</a>
  Title 1 <a href="#top">Go to top</a>
  a lot of text
  Title 2 <a href="#top">Go to top</a>
```

It works fine when i click a link on top it brings me to title1 or title2, and if i then click go to top it works, however if i scroll down to title1 or title2 and push go to top it's not working, when i try to load html in browser it works fine. Any ideas?

So to be clear it just doesn't work if i scroll, if i use links i can get back to top.

Comment: i also just tried the same thing in iphone and it works there to...

Comment: well it keeps getting wierder, it also works on another android phone i tried it on galaxy s and it works however on htc nexus one it doesnt :S